# Catching URL While Opening Email Client In Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have managed to open email client with this link:

```
mailto:demo@demo.com?subject=Inquiry%20regarding%20item%20%5BproductLink%5D%2C%20%5BproductName%5D&body=%0D%0AInquiry%20regarding%20item%20%5BproductID%5D%2C%20%5BproductName%5D!%0D%0A%5BproductLink%5D
```

Now i want to add URL of the current page in Subject. I know there is window.location.href function used for it. Now when i write window.location.href in subject to fetch URL, it displays window.location.href as subject instead of URL itself
  How can i implement it?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: the issue is when i type mailto:demo@demo.com?subject=windows.location.href...
it does not show location instead it shows windows.location.href. in subject. If you could help me implement this?

Comment: Well, how to you build the string in the first place? There is the + operator that concats two strings. Also, its `window` not `windows`

Comment: well mailto is normally placed in the href attribute of a link, and you can't run JS in an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location is a javascript object. I think you are using it as a string that's why it gives you 'window.location.href' as a string. I am a giving you a solution considering you are using jquery.....

```
<button id="sendEmail">dvfvdfv</button>
<script>
   $("#sendEmail").click(function(){
        //use window.location.href here
       var mailLink = 'mailto:demo@demo.com?subject=' + window.location.href+ '%20regarding%20item%20%5BproductLink%5D%2C%20%5BproductName%5D&body=%0D%0AInquiry%20regarding%20item%20%5BproductID%5D%2C%20%5BproductName%5D!%0D%0A%5BproductLink%5D';
       window.open(mailLink);
    });
</script>
```